# spring mvc download file not integrity

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

This is my code

```
@RequestMapping("/download")
@ResponseBody
public void download(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

    File file=new File("anyfile");
    String fileName="anyFileName";
    response.setContentType("application/force-download");
    try {
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="+ URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8"));//url这个是将文件名转码
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis =null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
        int i = bis.read(buffer);
        while (i != -1) {
            os.write(buffer);
            i = bis.read(buffer);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            bis.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Used this code,I can download file from my computer or my server.But when I download file from my server,I got a problem,the file not integrity.I don't know why,it don't happened when I test in my computer.Is there something wrong with my code? Or the reason for Tomcat?  My English is a little bit bad,sorry

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elb9G.png)

Comment: This has to be a duplicate. Classic Java I/O mistake : you should not ignore how many bytes were actually read from the file to your buffer, which is not guaranteed to be the exact buffer's size., change `os.write(buffer);` to `os.write(buffer, 0, i);`

Comment: The main line is File file=new File("anyfile"); be sure the path in your server is valid, and the code can access the file to download it

Comment: it's working!thanks bro